# Difference between rspec, capybara and cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can anyone tell me the difference between rspec, capybara and cucumber?

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~>2.1.0'
end
```

In JavaScript, I see Jasmine as my Unit-test framework. What do these three gems do in Ruby environment?

Answer (score 65):

`rspec` is a full-featured testing framework that will let you write what Rails considers unit tests, functional tests, and integration tests.  All of these exercise Ruby code through various layers of your Rails application.  All of these tests simulate requests to your Rails application, but don't actually run the application end-to-end over the network.

`cucumber` is a browser based integration testing framework, which allows writing automated tests that run against the entire Rails application accessed from within an automated web browser.  This allows you to write automated tests about in-browser behavior for JS or CSS.  Cucumber provides a unique angle on integration testing that uses plain english specification mapped to code via regular expressions.  This allows a more natural "Behavior Driven Development" model - describing what a web application should do, in plain language, from the perspective of the user.

`capybara` is a particular web driver powering the `cucumber` integration testing framework, that uses headless webkit.  This allows running a headless (without UI) Chrome/Webkit browser for automated testing.  This is very useful both in development, but especially on a remote test/continuous integration server.

So `rspec` and `cucumber` are similar in being testing frameworks with their own way of specifying things.  `rspec` has a nice DSL that's very readable while being actual code.  `cucumber` maps plain text descriptions to real code.

Though `cucumber` is usually used on top of capybara, you can also use `rspec` to drive `capybara` integration tests.  The tests are written in either rspec or cucumber, but `capybara` is an integration engine underneath.

Comment: The answer does include this, but I feel like it's important to emphasize that Capybara doesn't have to be used with Cucumber. Capybara can just be used with RSpec.